# Are there other methods for calculating of the center of gravity of a triangle?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, multivariable-calculus, trigonometry, triangles

Given a triangle in $\Bbb R^3$ with vertices $A = (x_1,y_1,z_1)$, $B = (x_2,y_2,z_2)$, and $C = (x_3,y_3,z_3)$ the formula to find the center of gravity $G$ is

$$G= \left(\frac{1}{3}\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^3x_i, \frac{1}{3}\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^3y_i, \frac{1}{3}\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^3z_i \right) \tag 1$$

where you simply take the component-wise average of the vertices. For my 16-year-old students I prove formula $(1)$ in $\Bbb R^2$ using the fact that

> Each median remains divided from the centre of gravity into two parts and the one to which the vertex belongs is double of the other.

What other methods are there to compute the center of gravity of a triangle in $\Bbb{R}^3$? Are there methods that don't use goniometry, or don't even consider the center as the intersection of the three medians? You could obviously compute it with a double-integral. Is there a way to compute this using a determinant or other methods of linear algebra?

Comment: Could you clarify your last paragraph? I'm not sure exactly what you're asking. Are simply asking for other ways to calculate the center of mass besides taking the component-wise averages of the vertices, or using calculus, or calculating the intersection of medians?

Comment: @MikePierce Hi and thank you very much for your interesting of my question unappreciated. Exactly I have thought if given three vertex $A(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ , $B(x_2,y_2,z_2)$ and $C(x_3,y_3,z_3)$ with a matrix (determinant) I can found fastely the relation $(1)$. If you want you can improved my question. Thank you again.

Comment: @Sebastiano I edited your question a lot. Please read it over to make sure I didn't change the meaning of your question. :) Also, I'm not quite sure what you mean by "*Each median remains divided from the centre of gravity into two parts and the one to which the vertex belongs is double of the other,*" so I didn't edit that. If you could clarify that would be helpful :)

Comment: @MikePierce It is perfect.  "*Each median remains divided from the centre of gravity into two parts and the one to which the vertex belongs is double of the other*" it is the translation of the geometric proof that it is explained in high school.